# Anylogic - How best to combine pedestrian flows with complex discrete event flows

Tags: anylogic

I have been working in other software with a complex discrete event model but am looking to add in pedestrian elements which the other software can't handle. I'm trying to explore how this works in AL PLE to understand if it will fit my needs but am struggling to combine pedestrian steps with the complexity of my process. In our existing model, walk times are represented by delays with triangle distributions and I was hoping it would be as simple as recreating the flow in AnyLogic and replacing these walk time delays with pedestrian 'goTo' steps but including the concept of queueing is completely stumping me.

I basically want to be able to have someone queue up for a work station, occupy the station but then do a complex task in that location, potentially including multiple delays, decisions and conditional seizes and releases, rather than a simple queue, seize, delay, release provided by a service. Because queues seemingly cannot be added without an attached service, I'm struggling with how to make this work.

As a 'simple' example, I've created the below to illustrate what I mean:
[example model screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1llwo.png)

My current ideas are:

Option 1 - Treat the service part of pedService as a holding space while a subprocess deals with the complexity: Set the pedService delay to an arbitrarily high number so the pedestrian stays there 'indefinitely' and use 'on begin service' to inject an agent into the subprocess below. When the new agent completes the sub process it sends a message back to set the remaining delay to 0 so the original pedestrian can then leave the service and continue on their way

Option 2 - Treat the pedService as just a queue and manually manage everything else with process blocks: Set the pedService delay to 0 and insert the whole subprocess between pedService and pedGoTo, which I think means they will stay in that location to complete all the subprocess tasks. I think this would mean I'd need a seize and release around those steps to represent a limited number of workstations available at the front of the queue?

Are either of these workable solutions and if so which is likely to be better/easier to implement? Is there some other option I'm missing that allows these two types of modelling to be combined more easily?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can mix the blocks from different libraries. If a pedestrian can not move to the next block, it will stay "hold" in the service queue.

In this short example below, the pedSource starts in the Rectangular Node; then they move to the service line (for queueing purposes). After servicing on the queue line, it moves into a Process Library block (where it selects output, have two different services requiring different resource pools).

In this case, the hold block is set to hold after N=1 agents (so only one passes). At the start of the pedGoTo1 it has a `hold.unblock()`, thus admitting one more agent into the complex process area.

As long as have something "blocking" the flowchart flow of the pedestrian agent (too small queue on the next block, a hold, etc) your agents will stay in the designated pedService lines (since they can't leave the pedService block).

[image: Sample model]

Comment: Thanks for this example - I think this will solve my problem!